# Most efficient way to add a masked array to another fortran

Tags: performance, fortran

I have a "masked array" that I would like to add to another array -- In other words, I have 3 arrays, `A`, `B` and `mask`.  My question is what is the most efficient (in terms of execution time) way to store the mask (as a logical array, as a real array of ones and zeros)?

**EDIT**

Here's a toy program you can play around with (if you have mpif77):

```
  program main
  implicit None
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer, parameter :: ntry=10000
  integer, parameter :: asize=1000000
  real,dimension(asize) :: A,B,maskr
  logical,dimension(asize) :: mask
  real*8 :: dd,dt,dtave,dtbest
  integer i

  do i=1,asize
     maskr(i)=mod(i,2)
     mask(i)=.False.
     if(mod(i,2).eq.0) mask(i)=.True.
  enddo

  A=1.0; B=1.0
  dtbest=1d33
  dtave=0.0
  do i=1,ntry
     dt=mpi_wtime()
     call add_arrays_logical(asize,A,B,mask)
     dt=mpi_wtime()-dt
     dtbest=min(dt,dtbest)
     dtave=dtave+dt
  enddo
  print*,"==== logical ==="
  print*,"Average",dtave/ntry
  print*,"Best",dtbest

  A=1.0; B=1.0
  dtbest=1d33
  dtave=0.0
  do i=1,ntry
     dt=mpi_wtime()
     call add_arrays_real(asize,A,B,maskr)
     dt=mpi_wtime()-dt
     dtbest=min(dt,dtbest)
     dtave=dtave+dt
  enddo
  print*,"==== Real ==="
  print*,"Average",dtave/ntry
  print*,"Best",dtbest

  A=1.0; B=1.0
  dtbest=1d33
  dtave=0.0
  do i=1,ntry
     dt=mpi_wtime()
     where(mask) A=A+B
     dt=mpi_wtime()-dt
     dtbest=min(dt,dtbest)
     dtave=dtave+dt
  enddo
  print*,"==== Where ===="
  print*,"Average",dtave/ntry
  print*,"Best",dtbest

  end

  subroutine add_arrays_logical(n,A,B,mask)
  integer n
  real A(n),B(n)
  logical mask(n)
  do i=1,n
     if(mask(i))then
        A(i)=A(i)+B(i)
     endif
  enddo
  end

  subroutine add_arrays_real(n,A,B,mask)
  integer n
  real A(n),B(n),mask(n)
  do i=1,n
     A(i)=A(i)+mask(i)*B(i)
  enddo

  end
```

**My results:**

(gfortran -O2)

```
==== logical ===
Average  1.52590200901031483E-003
Best  1.48987770080566406E-003
==== Real ===
Average  1.78022863864898680E-003
Best  1.74498558044433594E-003
==== Where ====
Average  1.48216445446014400E-003
Best  1.44505500793457031E-003
```

(gfortran -O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math)

```
==== logical ===
Average  1.47997992038726811E-003
Best  1.44982337951660156E-003
==== Real ===
Average  1.40655457973480223E-003
Best  1.37186050415039063E-003
==== Where ====
Average  1.48403010368347165E-003
Best  1.45006179809570313E-003
```

(pfg90 -fast) -- on a very old machine

```
==== logical ===
Average   5.4871437072753909E-003
Best   5.4519176483154297E-003
==== Real ===
Average   4.6096980571746831E-003
Best   4.5847892761230469E-003
==== Where ====
Average   5.3572671413421634E-003
Best   5.3288936614990234E-003
```

(pfg90 -O2) -- on a very old machine

```
 ==== logical ===
 Average   5.4929971456527714E-003
 Best   5.4569244384765625E-003
 ==== Real ===
 Average   5.5974062204360965E-003
 Best   5.5701732635498047E-003
 ==== Where ====
 Average   5.3811835527420044E-003
 Best   5.3341388702392578E-003
```

Of course, there are a few things that could influence this -- the compilers ability to vectorize the loops for instance -- so is there a rule of thumb about how something like this should be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by flops you mean floating point operations then the first option is obviously better since in that case you have 1 flop per loop iteration where mask(n) == .true. . Whereas for the second option you have 2 flops per loop iteration regardless of the value of mask(n).

OTOH, if you're interested in minimizing the time spent executing this function, why don't you try both versions on your data and test which is faster?

You might also want to test a version where you use the Fortran 90+ WHERE construct

```
where(mask) A = A + B
```

Comment: The code I'm working with is f77 (not my choice) -- so I'm avoiding `where` for that reason.

Comment: And yes, I mean in terms of time spent in the function.  I'll edit.

Comment: I can answer which is faster using `gfortran` since that is the only compiler that I have really easy access to -- but the code is meant to be run on all sorts of platforms with all sorts of compilers, so I was wondering if there is a rule of thumb for this sort of thing.  If there isn't a rule of thumb, it's probably not worth worrying about ...

Comment: @mgilson: The rule of thumb is "test and measure" ;-). So, out of curiosity, which one was faster? Did you try with different optimization options? E.g. "-O2" vs. "-O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math"?

Comment: with `gfortran` and `-O2`, `where` is the fastest followed by logical followed by real.  with `-O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math`, real is the fastest followed by `where` followed by logical. -- Of course, that's a simple test where every other element is masked (10000 tries, array size 1000000)

Answer (score 6):

Why not use "where"?

```
where (mask) A = A + B
```

Probably using the mask is fastest but the only way to know for sure is to measure.

Comment: The code I'm working with is f77 (not my choice) -- so I'm avoiding `where` for that reason.

Comment: Why would you think that using `mask` would be faster than `maskr`?  I would have thought that `mask` would lead to a more disordered memory access compared to `maskr` ...

Comment: @mgilson: Why would it be "disordered"? You're still iterating sequentially over A, B, and mask. In the fist case you're just not touching every element of A and B, but so what?

Comment: I think the idea is that you can't vectorize the loop with that if statement in there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute way to determine this in advance, as it is all of compiler, platform, and problem dependent.  As just one illustration, see the benchmarks via various Fortran compilers on Polyhedron's website.

... though take some care with Intel's benchmarks, as there are sometimes "funny" things therein (e.g. a few years ago Intel was fined USD 10 million by the Justice Department for wilfully/covertly impeding their compiler on anything other than Intel cpu's etc).

Having said so, a few thoughts:

1) Some strategies have a larger "set up cost", while others have higher "execution cost".  That is, the compiler/code takes some time to send the right bits to the cpu/microinstructions, which takes different amounts of  time with different strategies.  As such, one strategy may do better when adding short arrays, while another may do better with long arrays.

There may be comparable issues for the cases where your Mask is "dense" vs. "sparse" (see also below).

2) Your benchmark parameters are way too small.  One rule of thumb for benchmarking is that it should require at least a few - ten seconds of exe.  With your benchmarks, the execution times are so small that any tiny differences in clock's etc etc can have large relative effect.   To see this with clarity, run the standard Linpack benchmark for cases which require a fraction of second, 1-2 seconds, and 7-10 seconds.  Generally, the results under 1 second are meaningless for that example.

3) It is possible (or at least was, haven't tested lately) for F77 to run faster on some constructs under some conditions compared to F90/95 constructs (ForAll, Where, etc).

If your compiler allows using array sections as indices, then it is sometimes (e.g. when the Mask is "sparse") better to first create an integer array that holds the array indices that are True, and then add just the True array sections.  For example, if Integer iIndex(:) holds the .True. index values of Mask, then something like A(iIndex("bounds")) + B(iIndex("bounds")) can be quite efficient, since the cost of creating an index with logicals is smaller compared to general arithmetic operations. So in spite of the extra "set up" cost, if it is a "sparse" problem, then there may be only a small number of additions etc required.  Multiplications and higher arithmetic are even more "expensive", and so even more pronounced with sparse variations.  This is a kind of "home made" Where/ForAll construct.

Incidentally, there can be differences in exe even with (apparently) the same compiler. For example, Simply Fortran does quite a good job at producing fast code, it uses GCC/gFortran, compared to say Photran/Eclipse (on Windows), which also uses GCC/gFortran (at least on one of my machines).  This could be due to different ways of "interleaving" MingW or CygWin etc, and it could also be due to, for example, Simply Fortran's extensive optimisation for specific chips and instructions sets, etc.  Some of those issues don't arise on Linux etc, and so is an example also of "platform" matters.

Answer (score 0):

How about `A = A + maskr*B`? That removes any conditional behavior entirely, at the cost of scanning all three arrays regardless of the sparsity of your mask.